# Selenium webdriver - Tab control

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am facing a challenge in my project. There are two text box's in a page and where First text box will accept an email ID and when user move his control to next text box email ID from First text box will populate automatically in the second text box. I need to validate this test case.

I tried with following code,

```
WebElement emailElement = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
emailElement.sendKeys("ABCDEFG@g.com");
WebElement usernameElement = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
String userName = usernameElement.getAttribute("value");
assertEquals("ABCDEFG@g.com", userName);
```

Can someone help me with webdriver java code to fetch value from second text box(username).

Thanks in advance,

^Best regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this ?

```
WebElement emailElement = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
emailElement.sendKeys("ABCDEFG@g.com");

WebElement usernameElement = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
usernameElement.click(); // Here, autocomplete is done

String userName = usernameElement.getText(); // get the value
assertEquals("ABCDEFG@g.com", userName);
```

If you want to send the `TAB` key with selenium, you can do that :

```
emailElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

[All special keys are available here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/api.html#special-keys)

Comment: Thanks.... it worked well.
usernameElement.click(); //Either this
usernameElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB); //or this

Comment: What if I wanted to type something and then hit a tab? Can these be combined? I mean would `emailElement.sendKeys("abcd\\uE004")` work as expected?