# browser automation - tab out on mac

Tags: java, macos, selenium

Want to automate : Tab out on fire fox/ current browser on mac. Using from Java application.
Firefox 19 and 24

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9767643/1643558 not working

```
 someWebElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

What I have now :

```
private static java.awt.Robot robot;//in static block initialize this, at on time only one selenium is working so this is not multi threaded
 //inside function:
     try {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

        int delay = 250;//some sleep between keys is a good idea        
        LangUtils.sleep(delay);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Robot sendKeys :" + e, e);
        return false;
    }
```

Do you think this will help:
an apple script that takes browser name / brower window title as parameter and brings that window to the front and then sends tab event to that

Or have other solution?

Tried selenium native - that does not support it found threads that say that too.

Comment: why do you need to tab?

Comment: mimic a tab key press. was not working in earlier seleniums. and at times just focusing on another element does not help

Comment: sorry, i just don't understand the use case for this, nor understand why this would ever be needed

Comment: @sircapsalot http://stackoverflow.com/a/9767643/1643558 not working

 someWebElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);